# belongs_to and has_many in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many, belongs-to

I'm currently working in a project in which users can add users to a company, I want to save who added each user so there would be a belongs_to relation but one user can also add multiple users so that's a has_many.

```
class Passenger
  belongs_to :passenger, index: true
  has_many :passengers
end
```

I don't know if I can do this

Comment: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Comment: Passenger = User?

Comment: @Tun yes, my bad

Answer (score 1):

What you need is [self-jons](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins).

```
# app/model/passenger.rb
class Passenger < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :creations, class_name: 'Passenger', foreign_key: :passenger_id
  belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'Passenger', optional: true
end
```

You should have a migration with

```
class CreatePassengers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :passengers do |t|

      t.references :passenger

      # other attributes
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi, we are not using migrations. We add stuff directly to the model, for example
`field :added_by, type: String`

Comment: so you are not inherting `Passenger` from `ApplicationRecord` or `ActiveRecord::Base` ?

Comment: @Tun I guess he's using MongoID and not ActiveRecord

Comment: @CrescentStrike if you are using MongoDB (and MongoID) you should specify that on your question

Comment: Sorry, yes I'm using mongoid

Comment: Mongoid has [recursive embedding](https://docs.mongodb.com/mongoid/current/tutorials/mongoid-relations/#recursive-embedding)